# Coils in parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

Lets say we have 2 coils in parallel, hooked up to a voltmeter. A permanent magnet is then pushed in and pulled out of the first coil, in such a way that there is still flux through the second coil, but less than the first.

Will the voltage be lower if the second coil were to be removed from the circuit? If so, how so? The flux through the first coil would be the same no matter what, wouldn't it?

Illustration is not the best but perhaps it clears up the situation :)[image]

Comment: What is your difficulty in trying to answer this question?

Comment: Do you mean what confuses me about the situation, or level of education?

Comment: Yes I am asking what confuses you. I see that you have provided more explanation in response to the answer by Abhirup. Are you asking what the reading on V will be if two different EMFs are connected in parallel? I think [Different batteries connected in parallel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64509) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider two coils in parallel then we are actually increasing the area of cross section of the coils hence there will be more emf induced than having a single coil which would have a less area of cross section.
Yes, the flux through the first coil would be the same but then there is a second coil in the first case which results in more induced emf than in the second case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One thing that remains a little weird to me, is that the voltage would increase, even though they're connected parallel?

Comment: Think of it as two different cases both are independent of each other. For e.g. - If I say there is a circuit connected to a resistor of a certain resistance say 2 ohm having a cell of 2 V then the current flowing through it would be 1 A but if I change the resistance to 1 ohm then the current flowing through it changes to 2 A. Then you would say that it remains a little weird that the current would increase even though both the circuits are connected to a cell of same voltage. This example is not to disrespect you but to make you realize that they are two different cases. HOPE YOU UNDERSTAND!

Comment: This link is for your convenience : https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/faradays-law/latest/faradays-law_en.html