# Applying KVL to batteries with different EMF in parallel

Tags: electricity, electric-current, batteries

Consider the circuit diagram below-

[image]

Two batteries of different voltages are placed in
parallel, however as I was told that KVL is applicable to all loops if there is no varying magnetic fields, applying KVL to that loop yields (going in the clockwise direction) -$$-E_2+E_1=0 \\ \implies -6V+12V=0 \\ \implies 12V=6V$$
Which is absurd. I searched for the answer quite a while and found some similar question where an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64517) explicitly address this condition. But I want to know why I can't apply the KVL here when it is applicable for all loop?

Comment: You're neglecting the voltage drop over the resistors.

Comment: What about the potential differences across the resistors?

Comment: You can apply KVL, but you didn't.